# Excel Formula IF and IFERROR

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, if

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xyOst.jpg)

Hi Everyone,

I wondering what am I doing wrong here, why is I4 showing WIN when H4 is blank?
I had to use IFERROR on H4 to avoid #div/0.

Thank you,
Ali

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

had to change the order of the formula

from
=IF(H4>0, "WIN", IF(H4<0, "LOSS", IF(H4="", "")))
to
=IF(H4="", "", IF(H4>0, "WIN", IF(H4<0, "LOSS")))

All good now.

Answer (score 0):

See [this answer from StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35050151/excel-if-statement-comparing-text-with-number#:%7E:text=For%20the%20Excel%20compare%20operators%20%28e.g.%20%3C%2C%20%3D%2C,number%20values%20to%20text%20values%20for%20text%20comparison.) for the explanation of why you got the result you did in your original question. Comparison of text and numbers is one of those undocumented "features" of Excel.